# Understanding how to use preloadedState in redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

Im trying to save some things in locale storage and reHydrate the state on refresh.

And it works, but my initalState from my slice file is overwritten.

```
const reHydrateStore = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('culture') !== null) {
        return { login: { culture: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('culture')) } };
    }
};

export default reHydrateStore;
```

Then in configureStore:

```
preloadedState: reHydrateStore(),
```

my initalState object looks like this when I dont use reHydrateStore:

```
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    culture: '',
    error: null,
};
```

And when I use reHydrateStore:

```
const initialState = {
    culture: 'en-US',
};
```

Is there a way to configure the preloadedState to just replace the given prop?

I know I can set up all initalState props in the reHydrateStore method but that seems like awfaul way of doing it. Writing the same code twice feels very unnescesery imo.

**Edit:**

I moved the logic to the slice to be able to access the initalState.
But @Rashomon had a better approach imo and will try with that instead.
But here was my first solution:

```
const reHydrateLoginSlice = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("culture")) {
        return {
            login: { ...initialState, culture: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("culture")) },
        };
    }
};
export { reHydrateLoginSlice };
```

Comment: Have the same issue with mine, initialState on all slices are overwritten by preloadedState - wondering why initialState is required if overwritten by preloadedState 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74548806/how-to-get-initialstate-into-immer-slice-from-redux-preloadedstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can define your `initialState` as this to avoid rewriting the rest of keys:

```js
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    culture: '', // default value, will be overwrited in following line if defined in the storage
    ...(reHydrateStore() || {}), // if returns undefined, merge an empty object and use previous culture value
    error: null,
};
```

If you only need `culture` to be rehydrated, I would rehydrate only the value instead of an object to make it simpler:

```js
const initialCultureValue = ''

const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    culture: reHydrateCulture() || initialCultureValue,
    error: null,
};
```

Comment: Thx m8! I like this idea! I did something similar. I added my solution above. But your approach seems much cleaner. Will test with it!